# WiFi stops working after reboot in 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I am having a problem with the wifi in ubuntu. It worked fine when my laptop ran Windows, but not so much with Ubuntu. I followed the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbrYpqHadVQ but when I reboot my laptop, the wifi stops working once again. Does anybody know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install a driver using `make` and `sudo make install` rather than dkms, you have compiled and installed the driver for your currently running kernel version only. When Update Manager offers a later kernel version, known as linux-image, and then requests a reboot, you will be booting into a later, newer kernel version. You must recompile the wireless driver for the newer kernel version.

If you compiled from the *rtlwifi_new* repository, as the video suggests, then open a terminal and do:

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make clean
git pull
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot.

To make the driver parameter `ant_sel=2` persistent over reboots, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r rtl8723de
echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
modprobe rtl8723de
exit
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. After entering "make clean", what should I do in response to the questions? I just clicked enter, but am I supposed to do something else?

Comment: `make clean` should not produce any questions at all. It should simply list the build components from the old kernel version that were deleted. Are you *quite sure* that you previously did: `cd rtlwifi_new`?

Comment: Yes, I did cd rtlwifi_new previously. If it helps, the first prompt after make clean is: "rm: remove write-protected regular file 'halmac/halmac_88xx/.halmac_api_88xx_sdio.o.cmd'?"

Comment: Ah, haaa! 'write protected' suggests that you originally built the drive with `*sudo* make` Please try: `sudo make clean`

Comment: Ah, that worked. Thanks a lot! There is still one problem with the wifi though. The signal strength is bad and so I have to run this command: sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2. It seems to do the trick, but the effect resets after every reboot. Is there a way to make it so that I don't have to type this in terminal every time I boot up?

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.  Also, if my answe has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: This did not work. After I run the commands and reboot, I still find that I need to enter the "sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2" command. Am I supposed to type this "echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf" out as one line? After I do it the "root@" turns into ">". Is this normal?

Comment: It is  one line, however, I regret that I made an error and omitted the enclosing quote. Sorry! Please see the corrected line above.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you kindly!